# Trying to figure out how to make a gun animation with multi part gun

Tags: animation

I'm just starting with animating in Blender and i'm wanting to make a simple gun reload. I have 2 guns to work with but both are in multiple parts, ie. Slide mag receiver and handle. and i'm not sure how to bind them all together but still allow the mag and slide move independently. Any help would be appreciated and a little more in depth instructions would be awesome.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty broad question. What have you got so far? Could you post some screenshots of what you have already achieved, and where you are stuck at? Maybe show how you animated, any rigs and constraints you have used.

Comment: Im not really sure how to do much. i just needed. to know how to group a gun together so I can stream line this learning process for my self. I have next to now when it come to experience. Just trying to learn enough to see if i could have this as a  job or just a hobby.

Comment: Well you might want to take a look into constraints based animations, those are easy to grasp and adequate for machinery and more mechanical stuff. Along with parenting should cover most cases. Do a google search you will find plenty of videos about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question indeed, but sounds like proper parenting is all you need. Parent all your objects to logical groups of objects, like sleigh, magazine and so on. Create an empty around your gun, and parent gun, sleigh, magazine and all other to this empty.

Comment: I'm not completely sure how parenting works. i know how to select all the parts i want and then Ctrl+p to add them in to a object. I dint know if i had to rig it together. I'm really just starting out so don't know how to do much. havent found a good tutorial fitting to my needs.